# Database missing from myphpadmin but accessible through coldfusion

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm new to mySQL and myphpadmin, but a few weeks ago I figured out how to create a database, tables, add relationships and insert/modify records...great!  I've been creating coldfusion forms that access and update the database...perfect!  But I go back in to myphpadmin one day last week and my database is GONE!  The only databases there are "information_schema" and "test" (which is empty).  My database, "hr_database" is gone!  Crazy thing is (besides that), I can still use my ColdFusion forms to access and modify that database!

Anyway I can get it back in myphpadmin?  If you all need more info, just let me know!

Thanks so much!

Kirsten

Comment: Are you accessing both with the same user?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean.  I had looked around myphpadmin to see a place to "log in" or something, in case after restarting my computer I was someone logged out, but couldn't find anything like that.  Do you know how I can check that?  Thanks!

Comment: It means: what's the user you use to log in to phpMyAdmin. If you have root access (as @pendo sais), you can log in to phpmyadmin (usually from http://localhost/phpmyadmin) and check if your regular user has access to see the database.

Answer (score 1):

I think Fido is right.  The user you're logging into phpmyadmin probably doesn't have rights to see that database.  If you have root access, make sure to login with that.  If not, use the same user your CF DSN uses.

Comment: That makes sense but, where do you "log in" to myphpadmin?

Comment: What URL do you go to to access phpmyadmin?  That will help me answer that question.

Comment: http://localhost/phpmyadmin  ... clicking the link in Fido's comment above takes me right there.  Is there another URL (or parameter to add to the URL) that would specify the user?  Thanks very much.  I tried to upload the screenshot of the myphpadmin page, but because I don't have enough reputation points, it wouldn't let me add an image.  I can try uploading it somewhere and posting the link tonight - then you can see what I see.

Comment: If it's not prompting you to log in, that is truly bizarre.  Switch browsers or delete all your cookies and it should ask you to log in.  The credentials that you put in on the localhost/phpmyadmin login page will be the user you are viewing the databases as.  If that user has rights to see HR_Database, then you will see it.  If it doesn't, use your root user.

Comment: I switched to IE and deleted cookies, then opened myphpadmin again -- same screen.  There is a warning below about using root with no password.  Hopefully you can see my screenshot at this URL (I promise it's not a bad link...just a free service to upload images and share the link): http://postimage.org/image/frkelzulx/

Comment: You are logged in as root, as it is warning you that your root account has no password (that's not secure and you should fix it if you can).  So, the only other options (it seems) is that you are not connected to the same database instance as your Coldfusion server is.

Comment: I guess the last part is true, but not sure how to connect to it...I'm playing with that now.  What's more confusing is how I was connected to it before, and now I'm not!  Thanks for your help!  I may ask more once I get into that more, if that's alright.